# Constant sheaf takes disconnected set to product

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness, sheaf-theory

Let $S$ be a discrete topological space, and let $\underline{S}$ be the constant sheaf on a topological space $X$, meaning $\underline{S}(U)$ is the collection of continuous maps $U\to S$.

Am I correct in thinking that $\underline{S}(U)\cong S^n$ where $n$ is the number of connected components of $U$? Say $U=V\cup W$ where $V\cap W=\emptyset$, then we can have $s|_V:V\to \{p\}$ and $s|_W:W\to \{q\}$ where this is clearly continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the connected components of $U$ are open sets, then this is correct, since a continuous map $U\to S$ is uniquely determined by choosing a constant value on each connected component of $U$.  In particular, this is always the case if $U$ has only finitely many connected components.

However, if the connected components are not open, then not every choice of a constant value on each connected component will give a continuous map $U\to S$.  For instance, if $U$ is a Cantor set, then the connected components are just singletons, but not every map $U\to S$ is continuous.

Comment: Perhaps a more familiar example than the Cantor set is the set of rational numbers (as a subspace of the real line).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As a side question, how would one show that the stalks are all $S$?

Comment: The idea is that every section of $\underline{S}$ is constant in some neighborhood of $x$, so every germ of functions at $x$ is the germ of a constant function.

Comment: So an equivalent claim would be that every $x\in X$ belongs to some *open* connected set?

Comment: Equivalent to what?